# Convert files to string for Android App

Tags: java, android, string, pdf

What is the best way to convert common filetypes (.txt, .epub, .pdf) into a String in Java? I'd like to add this to my android app but I don't want to pay licensing fees. Are there any good open source libraries that can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this article: http://www.programcreek.com/2011/11/java-convert-a-file-into-a-string/

to convert the file to a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have all 3 file formats in one API, but for PDF format I suggest
PDFBox
It's an open source java API for manipulating PDF files ...

Comment: I couldn't use PDFbox, after adding the .jar to the /libs folder, I tried running the application and Eclipse crashed from running out of memory. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method to read a textual file into a string. It just returns the raw text. If you want to interpret PDFs and other eBook formats into human-readable strings, you'll need to locate libraries for each type that you want to handle.

```
static final int BUFF_SIZE = 2048;
static final String DEFAULT_ENCODING = "utf-8";

public static String readFileToString(String filePath, String encoding) throws IOException {

    if (encoding == null || encoding.length() == 0)
        encoding = DEFAULT_ENCODING;

    StringBuffer content = new StringBuffer();

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));
    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFF_SIZE];

    int bytesRead = 0;
    while ((bytesRead = fis.read(buffer)) != -1)
        content.append(new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead, encoding));

    fis.close();        
    return content.toString();
}
```